# ignore last comma from MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL TABLE: products

```
+--+------------+
|id| product_id |
+--+------------+
|1 | 689        |
|2 | 616,22,38  |
|3 | 666        |
|4 | 234,789    |
+--+------------+
```

SQL QUERY:

```
$id_pro= 23;
$sql = "UPDATE products SET product_id = CONCAT_WS(',',product_id, '$id_pro') WHERE id=3";
```

RESULT:

```
+--+------------+
|id| product_id |
+--+------------+
|1 | 689        |
|2 | 616,22,38  |
|3 | 666,23     |
|4 | 234,789    |
+--+------------+
```

**PROBLEM:** If **product_id** ends with a comma:

```
+--+------------+
|id| product_id |
+--+------------+
|1 | 689        |
|2 | 616,22,38  |
|3 | 666,       |
|4 | 234,789    |
+--+------------+
```

the Result is this:

```
+--+------------+
|id| product_id |
+--+------------+
|1 | 689        |
|2 | 616,22,38  |
|3 | 666,,23    |
|4 | 234,789    |
+--+------------+
```

how can i fix this, and make the query detect if the row ends with a comma and ignore it?

Comment: how does the comma get there in the first place?

Comment: @Ibu it didn't... just want to validate it just in case that happens

Comment: Fix. Data. Please. Read up on [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) - makes [SQL] life more enjoyable and robust.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
 REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(',',product_id, '$id_pro'), ',,', ',')
```

Comment: It works, but jeez it's curing the effect and not the cause. You really should normalize this data properly.